# How to get data from database to CheckboxList control inside a form view control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on asp.net user control.  I have used a gridview and a formview control.
on selecting a row in gridview it will hide the panel containing the grid and will display the panel containing the form view which is using the Grid's selected value as its key value and form loads in edit mode. for some extra use i had to place a checkbox list control in my form view control. and used SQL datasource to fetch data from databese to chkbox list. and used the same data key as formview control. Now my form view control works properly but my Checkbox list is not working properly as it cant get the selected value from grid view.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind your `CheckBoxList` on the `DataBound` event of your FormView.

Since you would need the same data key, you could use the `DataKey` property of the FormView.
If any additional data fields are required, you always have the `DataItem` property.

Done in this order, your CheckBoxList should work as expected.

Comment: nunepascal@ I can not use the datakey property in configuration mode of datasource.

Comment: nunepascal can you put snapshots here to make it easy t understand please?

Comment: nunespascal@ if u can it will be gr8 help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I used a session variable and it worked for me.
i used a session variable to store the selected value of grid in its selected index changed event and then used it as key value in checkbox list.